# Destroy/remove a meteor template in iron-router

Tags: meteor, iron-router, spacebars

I've just started using iron router in meteor. How do I hide or delete a template, or replace it with another?

I have two client-side routes. One shows a list of chatrooms a user can join:

```
Router.route('/', function () {
  this.layout('bodyLayout');
  this.render('roomList', {
    to: 'roomList'
  });
});
```

The other is for the chatrooms:

```
Router.route('/room/:_id', function () {
  this.layout('bodyLayout');
  var roomId = this.params._id;
  this.render('room', {
    to: 'room',
    data: () => {
      return { roomId }
    }
  });
});
```

Both of these have the same layout where they are `yield`ed close together:

```
<template name="bodyLayout">
    <!-- layout stuff -->

    {{> yield 'roomList'}}
    {{> yield 'room'}}

    <!-- layout stuff -->
</template>
```

Now, if I go to `/` and click a room, the room renders under it. But what I really want is for this to show either `room` OR `roomList`. How do I delete `roomList` when creating `room`, or can I replace it with `room` somehow?

Answer (score 0):

So ultimately I've found several solutions.

## Replacing a template

This is useful in a case like mine, if a certain location needs only one of several templates. It turns out that several routes can render to the same `yield`. we can remove one of the `yield`s:

```
<template name="bodyLayout">
    <!-- layout stuff -->

    {{> yield }}

    <!-- layout stuff -->
</template>
```

And remove the `to` attribute from the object we pass to `this.render`:

```
Router.route('/', function () {
  this.layout('bodyLayout');
  this.render('roomList');
});

Router.route('/room/:_id', function () {
  this.layout('bodyLayout');
  var roomId = this.params._id;
  this.render('room', {
    // We don't need this anymore:
    // to: 'room', 
    data: () => {
      return { roomId }
    }
  });
});
```

Alternatively, do give the `yield` a name:

```
<template name="bodyLayout">
    <!-- layout stuff -->

    {{> yield 'content' }}

    <!-- layout stuff -->
</template>
```

And give both routers the 'to' attribute that refers to the same `yield`:

```
Router.route('/', function () {
  this.layout('bodyLayout');
  this.render('roomList', { to: 'content'});
});

Router.route('/room/:_id', function () {
  this.layout('bodyLayout');
  var roomId = this.params._id;
  this.render('room', {
    to: 'content',
    data: () => {
      return { roomId }
    }
  });
});
```

## Removing a template from a router

If you do need to remove a template from a router, you can do this by giving the `this.render` function an empty string instead of a template name, thus telling it to render no template to this yield:

```
Router.route('/', function () {
  this.layout('bodyLayout');
  this.render('roomList', {
    to: 'roomList'
  });

  // Remove the room that was shown
  this.render('', { to: 'room'});
});
```